# Does get_post function counts as view?

Tags: php

I have a php file that is working outside wordpress's plugin and template system, and I am calling get_post to get the post's content. Does it count as a post view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't count post views. So no. Nothing counts as a post view.

If you're using a plugin or service that counts post views, then it would depend on that plugin or service, and how it measures views. You'd need to ask its author, but I feel safe saying that none of them would use `get_post()` to count views.

Comment: Just a remark. I don't use get_post to count view. Just worried about if by using get_post, it would automatically up the view count in the post.

Comment: If in doubt, you can test if it ups the post count by calling `get_post` lots of time on the same post ID. But think of it this way, if it did increase the post count then viewing a category archive would increase the post count of every post shown on the page. `get_post` just fetches the data in PHP, it won't render the page and execute any traffic stat JS libraries